# FFMPEG convert webm to mp4 not working

Tags: ffmpeg

I have upgrade to the latest ffmpeg which supports webm, but I can't seem to convert webm to mp4

```
ffmpeg -i filea.webM -sameq filea.flv
```

I am getting this error

```
swScaler: Unknown format is not supported as input pixel format
Cannot get resampling context
```

I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking to convert to mp4 but have added .flv output format in your command, try:

```
ffmpeg -i your_input_filename.webm -qscale 0 your_outfile_name.mp4
```

Comment: i can convert it to flv but not to webm

Comment: Don't use sameq, it DOES NOT mean same quality. See relevant post here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24541/mencoder-with-same-quality-output

Answer (score 4):

The late ffmpeg just need -i param

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.webm output_file.mp4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ffmpeg -i file.webm -strict -2 file.mp4
```

seems to be OK.

I use ffmpeg version 0.10.9-7:0.10.9-1~lucid1.

Comment: but this mp4 file is not playable on browser, why?

Answer (score 2):

In newer ffmpeg versions, "-sameq" option has been removed, you have to use "-qscale" instead.

```
ffmpeg -i your_input_filename.webm -qscale 0 your_outfile_name.mp4
```

Comment: but this mp4 file is not playable on browser, why?

Comment: `-qscale` is only for the legacy MPEG family of encoders: mpeg4, mpeg2video, mpeg1video, mjpeg etc. It is ignored by libx264 and libx265 and just about everything else.